# How to make unique font color for lines in a JCombobox?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I want to set the font color for the lines/entries in a JCombobox, unique for each line.  So basically when you click the dropdown arrow, you should see a few lines that are different colors, and I want to specify the colors myself based on their properties.  How should I go about doing this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a custom ListCellRenderer as such:

```
class Renderer extends JLabel implements ListCellRenderer {
```

and implement this method:

```
public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value,
            int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        // Get the selected index. (The index param isn't
        // always valid, so just use the value.)

        if (isSelected) {
            setBackground(list.getSelectionBackground());
            setForeground(list.getSelectionForeground());
        } else {
            setBackground(list.getBackground());
            setForeground(list.getForeground());
        }

        // Display the text
        String text = (String) value;
        setText(text);

        // Get the source
```

Then, depending on your source, use this.setForeground(Color color) to set the color of your text.  Finally,

```
return this;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably have to provide a custom renderer for your JComboBox, check out Sun's tutorial here:

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer

(Sorry for the lack of a link, can't post links yet since I'm a new member)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `ListCellRenderer`. You need to write custom class for this. Here is the full code to set foreground based on index (to avoid duplicates). You can also set custom selection background and background for this. See the comments in the code.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
class ListCellRendererDemo2 extends JFrame
{
Hashtable<Integer,Color> table;
JComboBox<String> c;

    public ListCellRendererDemo2()
    {
        createAndShowGUI();
    }

    private void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        setTitle("JComboBox Demo");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        table=new Hashtable<Integer,Color>();
        table.put(1,Color.RED);
        table.put(2,Color.BLUE);
        table.put(3,Color.GREEN);
        table.put(4,Color.GRAY);


        c=new JComboBox<String>();
        c.addItem("Item 1");
        c.addItem("Item 2");
        c.addItem("Item 3");
        c.addItem("Item 4");
        c.addItem("Item 5");
        c.addItem("Item 6");
        c.addItem("Item 7");
        c.addItem("Item 8");

        c.setRenderer(new MyListCellRenderer(table));

        add(c);
        setSize(400,400);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run()
            {
                new ListCellRendererDemo2();
            }
        });
    }
}
class MyListCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer
{
Hashtable<Integer,Color> table;

    public MyListCellRenderer(Hashtable<Integer,Color> table)
    {
        this.table=table;

        // Set opaque for the background to be visible
        setOpaque(true);
    }

    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList jc,Object val,int idx,boolean isSelected,boolean cellHasFocus)
    {
        // Set text (mandatory)
        setText(val.toString());

        // Set the foreground according to the selected index
        setForeground(table.get(idx));

            // Set your custom selection background, background
            // Or you can get them as parameters as you got the table
            if(isSelected) setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
            else setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: please isn't there any older thread, why to reincarnating any zombie, +1 for Initial Thread :-)